# Laravel - Gestión de las rutas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo estas 3 rutas que son muy parecidas, a nivel de lógica una calcula unos datos generales y las otras dos son "hijas" de esta porque son como subpartes.

Como vereis las 3 comparten algo en la ruta **/graficos / ventas / coches** que seria la estructura lógica para "mi" dentro de la API y luego es la acción una es **indice** , otra **consulta-piezas** y la otra **consulta-chapa**.

Tal como tengo el código las 3 rutas funcionan, el problema esta si la primera ruta que pongo la pongo abajo del todo entonces las rutas se me "solapan", por eso mi pregunta es como puedo mejorar estas rutas?

```php
Route::get('/graficos/ventas/coches/indice/{date?}', 'Api\VentasController@funnelConsultaPrincipal')
        ->name('api.graficos.ventas.consulta-principal');

Route::get('/graficos/ventas/coches/consulta-piezas', 'Api\VentasController@funnelConsultaPiezas')
        ->name('api.graficos.ventas.consulta-piezas');

Route::get('/graficos/ventas/coches/consulta-chapa', 'Api\VentasController@funnelConsultaChapa')
        ->name('api.graficos.ventas.consulta-chapa');
```

Comment: Si actualmente funcionan bien, ¿cuál es el problema en dejarlas con el orden actual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amm una forma mas bonita de verla pero que no agrega eficiencia seria asi:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/graficos/ventas/coches', 'middlewares' => []], function($coche){
   $coche->get('consulta-piezas', 'Api\VentasController@funnelConsultaPrincipal')
    ->name('api.graficos.ventas.consulta-principal');
   $coche->get('consulta-chapa', 'Api\VentasController@funnelConsultaChapa')
    ->name('api.graficos.ventas.consulta-chapa');
   $coche->get('indice/{date?}', 'Api\VentasController@funnelConsultaPrincipal')
    ->name('api.graficos.ventas.consulta-principal');
});
```

Regularmente recomiendo poner todas las rutas que esperan parámetros en la url hasta abajo. Dado que puede llegar a sobre escribir otras rutas. También es importante agrupar las rutas que responden a un mismo comportamiento.

Saludos.